# Trying to use tidy for a power analysis and using clmm2

Tags: r, statistics

I'm trying to do a power analysis on a clmm2 analysis that I'm doing.
This is the code for the particular statistical model:

```
test <- clmm2(risk_sensitivity ~ treat + sex + dispersal + 
sex*dispersal + treat*dispersal + treat*sex,random = id, data = datasocial, Hess=TRUE)
```

Now, I have the following function:

```
sim_experiment_power <- function(rep) {
  s <- sim_experiment(n_sample = 1000,
                      prop_disp = 0.10,
                      prop_fem = 0.35,
                      disp_probability = 0.75,
                      nondisp_probability = 0.90,
                      fem_probability = 0.75,
                      mal_probability = 0.90)
  broom.mixed::tidy(s) %>%
    mutate(rep = rep)
}
my_power <- map_df(1:10, sim_experiment_power)
```

The details of the function sim_experiment are not relevant because they are working as expected. The important thing to know is that it spits up a statistical clmm2 result. My objective with the function above is to do a power analysis. However, I get the following error:

> Error: No tidy method for objects of class clmm2

I'm a bit new to R, but I guess it means that tidy doesn't work with clmm2. Does anyone know a work-around for this issue?

EDIT: This is what follows the code that I posted above, which is ultimately what I'm trying to get.

You can then plot the distribution of estimates across your simulations.

```
ggplot(my_power, aes(estimate, color = term)) +
  geom_density() +
  facet_wrap(~term, scales = "free")
```

You can also just calculate power as the proportion of p-values less than your alpha.

```
my_power %>%
  group_by(term) %>%
  summarise(power <- mean(p.value < 0.05))
```

Comment: you can pull out the results with coefficients(summary(<model>)), convert to a dataframe with the rownames as one of the columns?

Comment: Is that what you meant to do with tidy?

Comment: Probably? I'm following someone else code - I edited my post to show what would come next. As I said, I'm a bit new to R, sorry if my reply sounds dumb.

Comment: Ok i see now. Yes you can work around it. I try to answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For what you need, you can write a function to return the coefficients with the same column name:

```
library(ordinal)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

tidy_output_clmm = function(fit){
  results = as.data.frame(coefficients(summary(fit)))
  colnames(results) = c("estimate","std.error","statistic","p.value")
  results %>% tibble::rownames_to_column("term")
}
```

Then we apply it using an example where I sample the wine dataset in ordinal:

```
sim_experiment_power <- function(rep) {
  idx = sample(nrow(wine),replace=TRUE)
  s <- clmm2(rating ~ temp, random=judge, data=wine[idx,], nAGQ=10,Hess=TRUE)
  tidy_output_clmm(s) %>% mutate(rep=rep)
}

my_power <- map_df(1:10, sim_experiment_power)
```

Plotting works:

```
ggplot(my_power, aes(estimate, color = term)) +
  geom_density() +
  facet_wrap(~term, scales = "free")
```

[image]

And so does power:

```
my_power %>% group_by(term) %>% summarise(power = mean(p.value < 0.05))
    # A tibble: 5 x 2
  term     power
  <chr>    <dbl>
1 1|2        0.9
2 2|3        0.1
3 3|4        1  
4 4|5        1  
5 tempwarm   1
```

Comment: can I use this in `broom.mixed` ?

Comment: Hi @BenBolker, you mean the example or code? Sure thing for both..

Comment: huh, that's weird. The ordinal (`clmm`) tidiers are in broom, not broom.mixed ...