# Looping over multiple multilevel ordered logits, tidying the results, dropping one observation at a time

Tags: r, loops, multilevel-analysis

I'm trying to loop over multiple multilevel ordered logistic regressions with random intercepts on the `country`, dropping one observation at a time from the main dataset, while producing one massive, augmented tidy data frame with the results. Given that I am just having trouble with the looping, and I can produce everything one data frame at a time, I will first show what I am trying to do with two data frames. Then, I will (poorly) attempt to solve the problem with a loop, which is the part for which I would greatly appreciate your assistance.

First, let's load some libraries:

```
# load libraries
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(tibble)
library(ordinal)
library(reprex)
library(magrittr)
```

Next, let's create some sample data:

```
# create original df in the right format
data0 = data.frame(country = rep(c("Algeria","Belgium","Canada","Denmark","England", "France"),times=10),
                     x1 = rep(0:1),times=30,
                     x2 = rnorm(n = 60, mean = 100, sd = 5),
                     y = rep(1:6),times=10)
data0$country = factor(data0$country)
data0$y = factor(data0$y)
data0 <- data0 %>% dplyr::select(country,x1,x2,y)
```

Building on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60206510/trying-to-use-tidy-for-a-power-analysis-and-using-clmm2), I'll create a custom tidier for `clmm2` models:

```
tidy.clmm2 <- 
  function(fit){
    results = as.data.frame(coefficients(summary(fit)))
    colnames(results) = c("estimate","std.error","statistic","p.value")
    results %>% tibble::rownames_to_column("term")
  }
```

Estimate the first model, tidy it, and augment it with confidence intervals, odds ratios, and model observation number:

```
# model 1: get the dataset with one less observation, removing the top row
data1 <- data0 %>% dplyr::slice(-1)

# model 1: estimate
m1 <- clmm2(y ~ x1 + x2, random=country, data=data1, Hess = TRUE)
summary(m1)

# model 1: get odds ratio and renames columns for model 1
or1 <- as.data.frame(exp(coef(m1)))
or1 <- or1 %>% rename(estimate.odds =1)
or1$term <- row.names(or1)

# model 1: tidy the model, get the CIs, and store the observation/model number
tidy_m1 <- tidy.clmm2(m1)
tidy_m1$obs <- m1$nobs[[1]]
tidy_m1$conf.low <- tidy_m1$estimate - (1.96 * tidy_m1$std.error)
tidy_m1$conf.high <- tidy_m1$estimate + (1.96 * tidy_m1$std.error)

# model 1: merge over the odds ratios and make final data
tidy_m1 <- left_join(tidy_m1, or1, by=c("term"))
```

Do the same for model 2, and bind the final output with model 1:

```
# model 2: get the dataset with one less observation, removing the top row
data2 <- data1 %>% dplyr::slice(-1)

# model 2: estimate
m2 <- clmm2(y ~ x1 + x2, random=country, data=data2, Hess = TRUE)
summary(m2)

# model 2: get odds ratio and renames columns for model 1
or2 <- as.data.frame(exp(coef(m2)))
or2 <- or2 %>% rename(estimate.odds =1)
or2$term <- row.names(or2)

# model 2: tidy the model, get the CIs, and store the observation/model number
tidy_m2 <- tidy.clmm2(m2)
tidy_m2$obs <- m2$nobs[[1]]
tidy_m2$conf.low <- tidy_m2$estimate - (1.96 * tidy_m2$std.error)
tidy_m2$conf.high <- tidy_m2$estimate + (1.96 * tidy_m2$std.error)

# model 2: merge over the odds ratios and make final data
tidy_m2 <- left_join(tidy_m2, or2, by=c("term"))

## Bind everything together to get a final data frame
tidy_final <- dplyr::bind_rows(tidy_m1,tidy_m2)
```

Here is my (poor) attempt at a loop, building on [this excellent post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62573810/how-to-make-loop-for-one-at-a-time-logistic-regression-in-r):

```
# create vector to store observation/data frame numbers
vector <- 1:59

# start of model
df_final <- purrr::map_dfr(1:59, 
               function(i) data.frame(model = i, 
                                      tidy.clmm2(glm(as.formula(paste0('y ~ ', i)), 
                                                     random=country,
                                                     Hess = TRUE,
                                                     data = data[vector]))))
```

How do I fix the above in line with what I was doing one model at a time? Don't worry about the `NaN`s, as I have only provided a highly-stylized example to facilitate responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I would improve your tidier function to do all of the extra tidying you were doing for each model (I'm assuming a tidier for this model class doesn't already exist in some package or other):

```
tidy.clmm2 <- 
  function(fit){
    results = as.data.frame(coefficients(summary(fit)))
    colnames(results) = c("estimate","std.error","statistic","p.value")
    tidy_fit <- results %>% tibble::rownames_to_column("term")
    or1 <- as.data.frame(exp(coef(fit)))
    or1 <- or1 %>% rename(estimate.odds =1)
    or1$term <- row.names(or1)
    
    #tidy the model, get the CIs, and store the observation/model number
    tidy_fit$obs <- fit$nobs[[1]]
    tidy_fit$conf.low <- tidy_fit$estimate - (1.96 * tidy_fit$std.error)
    tidy_fit$conf.high <- tidy_fit$estimate + (1.96 * tidy_fit$std.error)
    
    #merge over the odds ratios and make final data
    left_join(tidy_fit, or1, by=c("term"))
    }
```

I don't know `purrr`, but you can then use the base function `lapply` (which I guess is similar) to estimate the model and the get the tidy parameters on successively smaller datasets, befor passing the results to `bind_rows`.  Here I only do it for the first 10:

```
df_final <- lapply(1:10, function(i) {
  mod <- clmm2(y ~ x1 + x2, random=country, data=data0[(i+1):60,], Hess = TRUE)
  tidy.clmm2(mod)
  }) %>% bind_rows(, .id="Dataset")

> df_final
   Dataset term      estimate    std.error     statistic       p.value obs      conf.low    conf.high estimate.odds
1        1  1|2 -6.438544e+01          NaN           NaN           NaN  59           NaN          NaN  1.090838e-28
2        1  2|3 -3.518858e+01          NaN           NaN           NaN  59           NaN          NaN  5.221475e-16
3        1  3|4  2.961620e-01          NaN           NaN           NaN  59           NaN          NaN  1.344688e+00
4        1  4|5  2.971124e+01 2.207366e+01  1.346004e+00  1.783011e-01  59  -13.55313129  72.97561932  8.006253e+12
5        1  5|6  7.273474e+01          NaN           NaN           NaN  59           NaN          NaN  3.875214e+31
6        1   x1  2.054609e+01          NaN           NaN           NaN  59           NaN          NaN  8.376306e+08
7        1   x2 -8.899366e-02 3.978817e-03 -2.236686e+01 8.275733e-111  59   -0.09679214  -0.08119518  9.148514e-01
8        2  1|2 -7.093800e+01          NaN           NaN           NaN  58           NaN          NaN  1.556034e-31
9        2  2|3 -2.937359e+01 7.293763e+00 -4.027221e+00  5.644000e-05  58  -43.66936969 -15.07781910  1.750693e-13
10       2  3|4 -4.496101e+00 5.083061e+00 -8.845263e-01  3.764122e-01  58  -14.45889969   5.46669816  1.115240e-02
11       2  4|5  2.637413e+01 1.028467e+00  2.564412e+01 4.917528e-145  58   24.35833179  28.38992198  2.845364e+11
12       2  5|6  8.163547e+01 5.497370e-02  1.484991e+03  0.000000e+00  58   81.52771782  81.74321472  2.843364e+35
13       2   x1  1.821630e+01 5.424801e+00  3.357967e+00  7.851802e-04  58    7.58369175  28.84891081  8.151530e+07
14       2   x2 -7.476304e-02          NaN           NaN           NaN  58           NaN          NaN  9.279633e-01
15       3  1|2 -1.105259e+02          NaN           NaN           NaN  57           NaN          NaN  9.981611e-49
16       3  2|3 -4.660975e+01          NaN           NaN           NaN  57           NaN          NaN  5.723279e-21
17       3  3|4 -1.713909e+00 5.880686e+00 -2.914471e-01  7.707094e-01  57  -13.24005308   9.81223521  1.801602e-01
18       3  4|5  4.382707e+01          NaN           NaN           NaN  57           NaN          NaN  1.081073e+19
19       3  5|6  1.265335e+02 3.425069e-03  3.694335e+04  0.000000e+00  57  126.52681215 126.54023843  8.970400e+54
20       3   x1  3.988252e+01 5.999608e-04  6.647520e+04  0.000000e+00  57   39.88133918  39.88369103  2.092937e+17
21       3   x2 -2.175413e-01 2.615869e-04 -8.316215e+02  0.000000e+00  57   -0.21805405  -0.21702863  8.044943e-01
22       4  1|2 -6.646351e+01          NaN           NaN           NaN  56           NaN          NaN  1.365411e-29
23       4  2|3 -3.064726e+01 1.722949e+01 -1.778768e+00  7.527783e-02  56  -64.41706724   3.12253810  4.898489e-14
24       4  3|4 -3.327152e+00          NaN           NaN           NaN  56           NaN          NaN  3.589518e-02
25       4  4|5  3.188512e+01          NaN           NaN           NaN  56           NaN          NaN  7.039323e+13
26       4  5|6  7.214246e+01          NaN           NaN           NaN  56           NaN          NaN  2.143249e+31
27       4   x1  2.524262e+01 1.420819e+01  1.776624e+00  7.563011e-02  56   -2.60544100  53.09068131  9.177632e+10
28       4   x2 -1.139253e-01 5.874164e-04 -1.939430e+02  0.000000e+00  56   -0.11507663  -0.11277396  8.923246e-01
29       5  1|2 -5.520472e+01 1.024174e-03 -5.390171e+04  0.000000e+00  55  -55.20673057 -55.20271580  1.058994e-24
30       5  2|3 -3.324923e+01          NaN           NaN           NaN  55           NaN          NaN  3.631150e-15
31       5  3|4  7.955460e-01 5.817109e+00  1.367597e-01  8.912208e-01  55  -10.60598823  12.19708026  2.215650e+00
32       5  4|5  2.816002e+01 5.061437e+00  5.563641e+00  2.642027e-08  55   18.23960201  38.08043320  1.697228e+12
33       5  5|6  6.669283e+01          NaN           NaN           NaN  55           NaN          NaN  9.211492e+28
34       5   x1  3.351064e+01 1.024452e-03  3.271080e+04  0.000000e+00  55   33.50863540  33.51265125  3.576741e+14
35       5   x2 -1.850497e-01 1.173298e-03 -1.577175e+02  0.000000e+00  55   -0.18734938  -0.18275005  8.310630e-01
36       6  1|2 -3.286871e+01          NaN           NaN           NaN  54           NaN          NaN  5.312531e-15
37       6  2|3 -1.394418e+01          NaN           NaN           NaN  54           NaN          NaN  8.792619e-07
38       6  3|4  1.402239e+01          NaN           NaN           NaN  54           NaN          NaN  1.229831e+06
39       6  4|5  4.198923e+01          NaN           NaN           NaN  54           NaN          NaN  1.720640e+18
40       6  5|6  6.091421e+01          NaN           NaN           NaN  54           NaN          NaN  2.849095e+26
41       6   x1  2.791695e+01 9.151861e+00  3.050412e+00  2.285273e-03  54    9.97930271  45.85459762  1.330998e+12
42       6   x2  6.368881e-04          NaN           NaN           NaN  54           NaN          NaN  1.000637e+00
43       7  1|2 -8.540551e+01          NaN           NaN           NaN  53           NaN          NaN  8.106962e-38
44       7  2|3 -4.981897e+01          NaN           NaN           NaN  53           NaN          NaN  2.311503e-22
45       7  3|4  1.323464e-02          NaN           NaN           NaN  53           NaN          NaN  1.013323e+00
46       7  4|5  4.199212e+01 3.930682e+00  1.068317e+01  1.220384e-26  53   34.28798714  49.69626009  1.725630e+18
47       7  5|6  9.757102e+01          NaN           NaN           NaN  53           NaN          NaN  2.368942e+42
48       7   x1  2.742401e+01          NaN           NaN           NaN  53           NaN          NaN  8.130075e+11
49       7   x2 -1.149872e-01          NaN           NaN           NaN  53           NaN          NaN  8.913776e-01
50       8  1|2 -3.428518e+01 2.418647e+01 -1.417536e+00  1.563264e-01  52  -81.69065068  13.12029594  1.288655e-15
51       8  2|3 -1.468742e+01 2.158542e+01 -6.804326e-01  4.962306e-01  52  -56.99484187  27.61999711  4.181514e-07
52       8  3|4 -2.123523e+00 2.585943e+01 -8.211793e-02  9.345529e-01  52  -52.80800668  48.56096089  1.196095e-01
53       8  4|5  1.428943e+01 2.595126e+01  5.506258e-01  5.818902e-01  52  -36.57503632  65.15390302  1.606283e+06
54       8  5|6  3.811502e+01 1.071360e+00  3.557631e+01 3.257489e-277  52   36.01515820  40.21488826  3.573915e+16
55       8   x1  8.597913e+00 2.399747e+01  3.582841e-01  7.201307e-01  52  -38.43712837  55.63295352  5.420333e+03
56       8   x2 -3.759098e-02          NaN           NaN           NaN  52           NaN          NaN  9.631068e-01
57       9  1|2 -1.381079e+02          NaN           NaN           NaN  51           NaN          NaN  1.048377e-60
58       9  2|3 -5.910938e+01          NaN           NaN           NaN  51           NaN          NaN  2.133649e-26
59       9  3|4 -9.084277e+00          NaN           NaN           NaN  51           NaN          NaN  1.134354e-04
60       9  4|5  5.875811e+01          NaN           NaN           NaN  51           NaN          NaN  3.298542e+25
61       9  5|6  1.564752e+02          NaN           NaN           NaN  51           NaN          NaN  9.043358e+67
62       9   x1  4.528686e+01          NaN           NaN           NaN  51           NaN          NaN  4.654054e+19
63       9   x2 -2.132578e-01 2.314244e-05 -9.215010e+03  0.000000e+00  51   -0.21330318  -0.21321246  8.079478e-01
64      10  1|2 -5.537366e+01 2.398432e+01 -2.308744e+00  2.095778e-02  50 -102.38292260  -8.36439034  8.943892e-25
65      10  2|3 -2.567911e+01 1.644416e+01 -1.561594e+00  1.183836e-01  50  -57.90967366   6.55145288  7.042130e-12
66      10  3|4 -3.561160e+00 1.421535e+01 -2.505152e-01  8.021890e-01  50  -31.42323652  24.30091746  2.840587e-02
67      10  4|5  2.622061e+01 1.739894e+01  1.507024e+00  1.318045e-01  50   -7.88130243  60.32253224  2.440441e+11
68      10  5|6  6.147091e+01          NaN           NaN           NaN  50           NaN          NaN  4.971402e+26
69      10   x1  1.720323e+01          NaN           NaN           NaN  50           NaN          NaN  2.959845e+07
70      10   x2 -6.799849e-02          NaN           NaN           NaN  50           NaN          NaN  9.342619e-01
```

Comment: thank you so much! Indeed, your code works with a small number of loops. However, I ran your code all night on my data (2028 observations; 1540 loops), and it broke down. There are two errors: 1) in R Studio, it says "missing argument to function call" in the left hand panel--i.e., there is the yellow exclamation point icon; 2) "Error in eval(substitute(expr), data, enclos = parent.frame()) : Grouping factor must have 3 or more levels". The latter error appears unique to [clmm2](https://github.com/cran/ordinal/blob/master/R/clmm2.R). Do you have any ideas? Thanks again!

Comment: I guess the latter error occurs when you take away so many levels you no longer have an ordinal regression.  Although I don't know what you are ultimately trying to do,  it seems there should be a better way to achieve it than running this model and assembling the results over 1540 iterations.

Comment: Which line has the warning?

Comment: Basically, I pre-processed the data through matching to reduce the model dependence. Then, I am running these multilevel ordinal regressions on each matched sample to see how the effect varies across the different the bias-variance tradeoffs that occur as I drop observations but approach maximum balance (references [here](https://www.aeaweb.org/articles?id=10.1257/aer.p20151020) and [here](https://gking.harvard.edu/publications/balance-sample-size-frontier-matching-methods-causal-inference)). The latter R package only works on basic linear regression--hence the brute force approach here.

Comment: It doesn't allow me to tell which line has the error, because the console is full. Any idea on how to create an indicator and stopper if the error occurs so that we can figure out where the error occurs?

Comment: I don't know sorry

Comment: No worries and thank you, George! I am marking this one as complete. It was a great solution, and I really appreciate your help! For now, I will just run a couple different versions of the model with less data and iteratively check where the error occurs.

Comment: I just added print(i) to track iteration number and solved it that way.

Comment: glad you got it sorted.